# Re-using a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am dequeueing a vanilla `UICollectionViewCell` and setting its background color:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellId forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Of course, this color is being set every time a cell is recycled, even though it never changes.

Is there a way to only set the color when the cell is first created *without* subclassing `UICollectionViewCell` for such a small thing? I ask because `UITableView` allows for this without subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without subclass UICollectionViewCell in StoryBoard like [this code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7p84ydv6jffasnc/TestCollectionVew2.zip)

But UICollectionViewCell have nothing in its contentView, you should subclass then you can drag many other view you like to it and hook up with IBOutlet. Initial setting for these views are in awakeFromNib if Cell create in storyboard or Xib, in init if cell create by code.